# What is the difference between these two function declarations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

In JavaScript we can say:

```
function a() {};
```

Or we could say

```
var a = function() {};
```

Can anyone explain to me how exactly these differ, which, if any, is more preferable, and under what circumstances would one use each?

Any links or external reading would also be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know there is no difference, except that only the latter way can be used in objects.

Comment: @pimvdb there's a pretty big [difference](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#functions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One is a function declaration and one is a function expression.

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 2):

***First***

```
function a() {};
```

This can be either FunctionDeclaration or FunctionExpression.
We can only knows if it's a FunctionDeclaration or a FunctionExpression, depending on the context where it appears.

example #1)

```
0,function a() {} //FunctionExpression
```

example #2)

```
(function a() {} ()); //FunctionExpression
```

example #3)

```
var b = function a() {}; //FunctionExpression
```

example #4)

```
foo(function a(){}); //FunctionExpression
```

***Second***

```
var a = function() {};
```

This is clearly a FunctionExpression for two reasons.

1) The right hand side of an assignment

2) anonymous function

useful links :

http://sweatte.wordpress.com/syntax/javascript-idioms-and-gotchas/

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Answer (score 0):

one is a function declaration the other is an object declaring a function. This is the basis of virtually every object oriented javascript tutorial.

Comment: isn't every function also an object in js?

Comment: @Simon yes. (almost) everything is an object